# optimizing code and how to take selected region of active spreadsheet as input-google docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written script for changing a format like `12.4/12/12.03` into `12:40:00/12:00:00/12:03:00`
Here's the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows= sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows=rows.getNumRows();
  var values=rows.getValues()
  var column = [];
  var p = 0;
  var k = "H";

   for (var i=0;i<numRows;i++) {

    // var cell = 
    //Split the string a the .
  var  string = values[i][7].split(".");

     string[0] = string[0].toString();
     p = i+1;
     k = "H"+p;
     var cell = sheet.getRange(k);
     if(string[1]){
       string[1] = string[1].toString(); 
    // if the second part is like 4 in 12.4 you set it to 40

     if(string[1]!=0) {
    if (string[1].length == 1 )
    {   string[1] += "0";}
     }
    // Set the row value to the format you like, here : 12:40:00/12:40
      var changed_format = string[0] + ":" + string[1] + ":00";
     values[i][7]=changed_format;
     p = i+1;
     k = "H"+p;
     cell.setValue(changed_format);     
}
     else {
       var changed_format = values[i][7]+":00:00";
     cell.setValue(changed_format);

     }    
   }
```

In the above code, I have mentioned columns...i.e., I have to run this script for each column...every time... ex: `values[i][7]` `k="H"+p` for `8th column`. So, can anyone plz tell me how to do...all at a time...and if possible reduce my code..(optimize)..and also..if is it possible to do like this : if I select the column in the spreadsheet and the changes done by the script applies to that selected region...I mean I want my script to take the selected region as input...is it possible to do..if how.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One key to optimize your code is to reduce the number of calls to Google services and try getting them done using JavaScript. Here is an optimized version that you could use. 
Note that I havent tested it - so if you come across minor syntax errors, feel free to fix them or give a shout if you cannot fix them.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows= sheet.getDataRange();
  var values=rows.getValues(); 
  var COL_H = 8;

  var numRows=values.length ; // Length of array = nuymRows. rows.getNumRows();
  var column = [];
  //var p = 0;
  //var k = "H";
  var destArray = new Array();

   for (var i=0;i<numRows;i++) {

    // var cell = 
    //Split the string a the .
    var  string = values[i][7].split(".");

     string[0] = string[0].toString();
     //p = i+1;
     //k = "H"+p;
     //var cell = sheet.getRange(k);
     if(string[1]){
       string[1] = string[1].toString(); 
       // if the second part is like 4 in 12.4 you set it to 40

       if(string[1]!=0) {
         if (string[1].length == 1 )
         {   string[1] += "0";}
       }
      // Set the row value to the format you like, here : 12:40:00/12:40
      var changed_format = string[0] + ":" + string[1] + ":00";
      //values[i][7]=changed_format;
      //p = i+1;
      //k = "H"+p;
      //cell.setValue(changed_format);   
      destArray.push([changed_format]);  
    }
    else {
       var changed_format = values[i][7]+":00:00";
       //values [i][7] = changed_format;
     //cell.setValue(changed_format);
      destArray.push([changed_format]);
     }
   }
   var destRange = sheet.getRange(1, COL_H, destArray.length, 1);
   destRange.setValues(values);
}
```

TIP: Putting formatted code in the question helps readability

Comment: thank you... @Srik ..From next time onwards...I'll put formatted code..and what's desArray.push...in your code..?? and also is there any way to pass the selected region of the spreadsheet as the parameters or something (as input to the script)..??

Comment: `destArray.push` adds a new element to the array. Remember, when using `setValues`, you have to pass a 2D array. SO each element in the array is an array itself. 
To work with the selected region, you can simply use `getActiveRange()` instead of `getDataRange()`